# Grouping of combinations with elements in common

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, elementary-set-theory, clustering

Consider all the $\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\k\end{array}\right)$ possible combinations of $k$ elements from a fixed set of $n$ elements. Let’s now form groups of these combinations with the following property: In each group there exist at least one combination with at least $s<k$ elements in common with all other combinations of the group. Is it possible to find the minimum number of groups that cover all the $\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\k\end{array}\right)$ combinations, as a function of $n$, $k$ and $s$? The exact number would be great, but some (sharp) upper limit would also be very useful.

In other words, I would like to find the $s$-net covering number of the set of all $\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\k\end{array}\right)$ possible combinations, with respect to the distance metric corresponding to the number of non-overlapping elements.

Comment: This is a very interesting problem.  How did you come up with it?  Have you got any ideas or partial solutions or sample numbers that you can share?

Comment: This is the *domination number* of the *generalized Kneser graph*, so you might find something by searching for these terms.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that you're trying to cover all binary codewords of length $n$ with $k$ ones with spheres of Hamming distance radius $2(k-s)$ centred at such a codeword.